# C# Multidimensional string Lists

Tags: c#

For my knowledge I want to understand about multidimensional string Lists in C#.  Please can some one explain me with good example code of creating multidimensional string Lists and also retrieving data from it.

I want examples for the following

1. `List<string[]>`
2. `List<string[,]>`
3. `List<List<string>>`

Answer (score 1):

Declare them just like any other list type:

```
List<string[]> list1 = new List<string[]>();
List<string[,]> list2 = new List<string[,]>();
List<List<string>> list3 = new List<List<string>>();
```

and access them like so:

```
// First and third use identical indexers:
string s1 = list1[0][0];
string s3 = list3[0][0];

// Second is similar, just with a multidimensional indexer instead
string s2 = list2[0][0,0];
```

Comment: Most people who come new to C# confuse List with LinkedList, which are two completely different data-structures. List in C# is Vector in C++. Vector is really the better name for it, List really creates confusion.

Comment: @AmmarSalman How anyone can consider `Vector` a better name for a list of things is beyond me. The .NET Framework is not in the business of naming things just so developers coming from C++ feel right at home. I consider naming a list of things `List` the better name by far.

Comment: @InBetween I personally came from C# to C++, not the other way around. And vector makes more sense (for me). In programming, whenever I hear List my mind goes to the Linked List definition in Data-Structures. In most data structure books you will see them talking about linked lists which hold pointers and stuff, and no one talks about Lists as what you just described them. The definition you just described is part of the array definition. It is just an array that can actually grow in size. Thus vector makes more sense. Just an opinion

Comment: @AmmarSalman That's a reasonable argument against using "List", but it doesn't explain why you think "Vector" is a better fit. Any argument I can think of in favor of "Vector" involves a bit of sideways thinking, like perhaps maybe it makes sense if you consider it as an array with a mutable magnitude and number of dimensions... yeah, that stopped making sense even as I was typing it out. As far as to the name being reminiscent linked list, C# has a collection called `LinkedList` too, so really you can just see `List` as being a linked list without the linking.

Comment: C#'s list and linkedlist are two completely different data-structures. The List is actually an array that can grow in size. All its elements have to be next each other in memory. While in LinkedList they don't, and each member should have a pointer to the next element. Vector means an array that can grow in size by its definition, which is why it, for me, makes more sense

Comment: @AmmarSalman First, I was talking about conceptually, not literally. _Conceptually speaking_, the only difference between `List` and `LinkedList`, is that `List` is just a collection of objects, where `LinkedList` is a collection of objects that are linked to each other sequentially. Second, your explanation in favor of vector is tautological, since you just basically said that "Vector is better because a vector means the array can grow in size". That's just a paraphrased regurgitation of the C++ definition of a vector, not a defense as to why that word specifically is better.

Comment: @Abion47 - thanks for you reply.  Please can I ask that how can I add values to each of the above List variables?  Also how can I use Foreach statement with these lists?

Comment: @kami The same way you would with any other `List` type. Just use `list.Add` and `foreach (var a in list) { ... }` which will allow you to add an array or iterate through the arrays, respectively.